# How to make system wide alias for "ls -l"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I would like to have

```
alias ll="ls -l"
```

to be system wide.

How is that done on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add it in to `/etc/bashrc`. This will (or should) get called on login by every user who uses bash.

Comment: My machine (Ubuntu 12) doesn't have /etc/bashrc or any references to it in /etc/profile, ~/.bashrc or elsewhere.  The place I found that was best to do this, decoupled from the system's files and thus better for maintaining customizations with something like Puppet, is to place a file in /etc/profile.d/

Comment: I believe the correct location is actually `/etc/bash.bashrc` FWIW

Answer (score 21):

```
# echo "alias ll='ls -l'" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

and make sure that this file is executed whenever an user enters a shell by adding the following in `~/.bashrc`:

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bash.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: This answer was helpful. In Ubuntu 14.04, when I opened my `.bashrc` file, near the end, there's a pre-created section similar to the `if [...]` @quanta mentions, except is uses `.bash_aliases`.  All I had to do is echo the alias into `echo "alias ll-'ls -l'" >> ~/.bash_aliases` since `.bashrc` already had something setup in this environment.  And I closed/re-opened putty.

Answer (score 8):

If your user's $HOME/.bashrc contains the usual

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Then put it in /etc/bashrc. If it doesn't then put it in /etc/profile from where it will at least be read for login shells.